# DBeaver does not start on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, dbeaver

I have Ubuntu 18.04.2LTS
GNOME 3.28.2
Java:
~$ java -version
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)

```
    ~$ dbeaver
    2019-07-01 10:19:38.974 - Create display
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.157 - > Start org.jkiss.dbeaver.core [6.1.1.201906240635]
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.161 - DBeaver 6.1.1.201906240635 is starting
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.161 - OS: Linux 4.18.0-25-generic (amd64)
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.161 - Java version: 11.0.2 by Oracle Corporation (64bit)
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.162 - Install path: '/usr/share/dbeaver'
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.162 - Instance path: 'file:/home/ilya/.dbeaver4/'
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.162 - Memory available 64Mb/1024Mb
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.180 - Starting RMI server at 21449
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.222 - Run workbench
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.228 - > Start org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt [0.14.500.v20190214-0851]
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.229 - > Start org.eclipse.e4.core.services [2.1.400.v20181215-2145]
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.230 - > Start org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts [1.8.0.v20190214-1713]
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.238 - > Start org.eclipse.e4.ui.services [1.3.400.v20190212-2214]
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.265 - > Start org.eclipse.e4.ui.di [1.2.500.v20190214-1316]
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.297 - > Start org.eclipse.emf.common [2.15.0.v20181220-0846]
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.312 - > Start org.eclipse.emf.ecore [2.17.0.v20190116-0940]
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.363 - > Start org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi [2.15.0.v20180706-1146]
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.493 - > Start org.eclipse.core.filesystem [1.7.300.v20190218-2054]
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.541 - > Start org.eclipse.core.resources [3.13.300.v20190218-2054]
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.686 - > Start org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt [1.3.400.v20190224-1542]
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.695 - > Start org.eclipse.core.expressions [3.6.300.v20190218-1215]
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.711 - > Start org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt [0.14.500.v20190220-1002]
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.814 - > Start org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings [0.12.400.v20190131-1604]
    2019-07-01 10:19:39.872 - > Start org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions [0.15.300.v20190213-1308]
    2019-07-01 10:19:40.157 - > Start org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt [0.13.400.v20190223-1254]
    2019-07-01 10:19:40.253 - > Start org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme [0.12.200.v20190212-2214]
    2019-07-01 10:19:40.295 - > Start org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui [5.1.26.201906240635]
    2019-07-01 10:19:40.448 - > Start org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core [2.6.0.v20190215-2242]
    2019-07-01 10:19:40.450 - > Start org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations [2.5.300.v20190202-1801]
    2019-07-01 10:19:40.454 - > Start org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine [2.6.200.v20190215-2242]
    2019-07-01 10:19:40.459 - > Start org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata [2.4.300.v20190215-2242]
    2019-07-01 10:19:40.471 - > Start org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler [1.4.200.v20181102-0649]
    2019-07-01 10:19:40.472 - > Start org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatechecker [1.2.100.v20180827-1122]
    2019-07-01 10:19:40.477 - > Start org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository [1.3.100.v20180822-1302]
    2019-07-01 10:19:40.477 - > Start org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository [2.4.300.v20190215-2242]
    2019-07-01 10:19:40.540 - DBeaver is stopping
    2019-07-01 10:19:40.540 - Stop RMI server
    2019-07-01 10:19:40.575 - < Stop org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.mssql.ui [1.0.10.201906240635]
    2019-07-01 10:19:40.576 - < Stop org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.mssql [1.0.105.201906240635]
    2019-07-01 10:19:40.576 - < Stop org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.oracle [2.1.96.201906240635]
    2019-07-01 10:19:40.576 - < Stop org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.ui.tipoftheday [1.0.17.201906240635]
```

~$ apt policy dbeaver-ce
dbeaver-ce:
  Установлен: 6.1.1
  Кандидат:   6.1.1
  Таблица версий:
 *** 6.1.1 500
        500 https://dbeaver.io/debs/dbeaver-ce  Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     6.1.1~ubuntu16.04 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/serge-rider/dbeaver-ce/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

What to do? How do I get dbeaver to run?

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem, unistalled/installed via snap, ando didnt work. but a simples refresh got it fixed.

```
 snap refresh --edge dbeaver-ce
```

Comment: didn't worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Actually my machine got stuck and I had to force an emergency shut down. After my machine started I could not open DBeaver. After struggling with it I decided to reinstall it.

Before you uninstall make sure your DB connections are saved to a different folder.
Copy these files in this folder:

> c:\Users{yourusername}\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspace6\General\

(this is for windows but for ubuntu it should be *$XDG_DATA_HOME/DBeaverData/workspace6/General* [see DBeaver wiki for details](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Workspace-Location))

Then you can start to uninstall the application using Programs and Features (on Win10), for Ubuntu you can use the following command: *sudo apt-get remove DBeaver*

From there you should already know what are the steps to install it and do not forget to copy your workspace files (DBConnections, etc.) back to the original location.

If DBeaver is still not opening then the workspace got corrupted, maybe a file was not closed properly (or character coding issue?) but the most safety way to fix it is: add your connections one by one again.